# pysnmp convert (.my) to (.py) issue. Why always asks me to install the package?

Tags: python, failed-installation, pysnmp

I am using Linux v.16

I installed pysnmp package succesfully. I am trying to convert the `.my` to `.py` but I am facing errors:

**1.**
 using this command: `smidump -f python custom-mib.my | libsmi2pysnmp>custom-mib.py`

The output was:

```
smidump: module 'custom-mib' contains errors, expect flawed output
smidump: aborting due to severe parsing errors
smidump: use the -k option to force continuation
The program 'libsmi2pysnmp' is currently not installed.
            You can install it by typing: apt install python-pysnmp4
```

( the package is already installed. To make sure, when I apply the command: `apt install python-pysnmp4`, the result is "`python-pysnmp4 is already the newest version`"

**2.**
When I use the command: `build-pysnmp-mib -o custom-mib.py custom-mib.my`,
I am facing the same error saying to install the same package.

Answer (score 1):

What pysnmp version are you running? It it's past 4.3.x (inclusive), you do not really need to do any MIB conversion by hand -- it's all [being done automatically](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/faq/pass-custom-mib-to-manager.html) by pysnmp/pysmi packages interplay. You just [pass pysnmp MIB name](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#custom-asn-1-mib-path) in your query -- it should be able to do the rest.

If you can't upgrade to the latest pysnmp version, you can use the `mibdump` tool from the pysmi package instead of (long time obsolete) `smidump`/`build-pysnmp-mib`/`libsmi2pysnmp` toolset to convert .my into .py and [pass those .py MIBs](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#custom-pysnmp-mibs-location) to your old pysnmp instance.

Here is an example `mibdump.py` tool invocation that converts the `IF-MIB` into pysnmp classes:

```
$ pip install pysmi
...
$ mibdump.py --mib-source /my/mib/dir \
             --mib-source http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@ \
             --destination-format pysnmp \
             IF-MIB
Source MIB repositories: /my/mib/dir, http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@
Borrow missing/failed MIBs from: http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@
Existing/compiled MIB locations: pysnmp.smi.mibs, pysnmp_mibs
Compiled MIBs destination directory: /home/user/.pysnmp/mibs
MIBs excluded from code generation: INET-ADDRESS-MIB, PYSNMP-USM-MIB, RFC-1212, RFC-1215, RFC1065-SMI, RFC1155-SMI, RFC1158-MIB, RFC1213-MIB, SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB, SNMP-TARGET-MIB, SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC, SNMPv2-TM, TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB
MIBs to compile: IF-MIB
Destination format: pysnmp
Parser grammar cache directory: not used
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes
Rebuild MIBs regardless of age: no
Dry run mode: no
Create/update MIBs: yes
Byte-compile Python modules: yes (optimization level no)
Ignore compilation errors: no
Generate OID->MIB index: no
Generate texts in MIBs: no
Keep original texts layout: no
Try various file names while searching for MIB module: yes
Created/updated MIBs: IANAifType-MIB, IF-MIB
Pre-compiled MIBs borrowed: 
Up to date MIBs: SNMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-MIB, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC
Missing source MIBs: 
Ignored MIBs: 
Failed MIBs:
```

The compiled MIBs end up in `~/.pysnmp/mibs` unless you change default destination directory.

Comment: Hello, It said i have downloaded the latest pysnmp version. I have uploaded the Mib files with (.my) extension, i want to convert them to (.py). IWhat query should i use?

Comment: Hello,But i am using Ubuntu 16, in which pysmi package is absent: https://repology.org/metapackage/python:pysmi/versions. Correct?

Comment: And yes, it is version 4.3

Comment: Can you temporarily install pysmi from PyPI somewhere, generate the pysnmp MIB modules you need and then use them without pysmi being installed in production?